# LevelScheme for ListPlot Joined->False exceeds the size of the Panel

Tags: graphics, plotting, levelscheme

In two side by side panels, using LevelScheme, I output the same data using ListPlot. In the first panel I use option Joined->**False**, while in the second Joined->**True**. The data in the second panel is properly limited by the size of the panel, while in the first panel it goes beyond the panel limits. So, my question is: how to make objects being displayed be cut exactly by the size of the panel, if even explicitly specifying the PlotRange in ListPlots doesn't make any difference?

```
<< "LevelScheme"`
Figure[{
  Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, {1, 2}, XGapSizes -> {.5}],

  FigurePanel[{1, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}],
  RawGraphics[
   ListPlot[Table[{.1 x, Sinc[.1 x]}, {x, Range@200}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},Joined->False]
   ],

  FigurePanel[{1, 2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}}],
  RawGraphics[
   ListPlot[Table[{.1 x, Sinc[.1 x]}, {x, Range@200}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Joined -> True]
   ]

  },


 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}]
```

results in

[image: result of the aforementioned code execution in Mathematica 9]

Answer (score 1):

You should prepend to the code of your question

`<< "LevelScheme`"`

However, this doesn't open with my version of MMA (10.0)

As an alternative one could use

```
a = ListPlot[Table[{.1 x, Sinc[.1 x]}, {x, Range@200}],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}},
  Joined -> False,
  AspectRatio -> 1.5,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"(a)"}, {0.3, 0.95}]];

b = ListPlot[Table[{.1 x, Sinc[.1 x]}, {x, Range@200}],
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1}},
  Joined -> True,
  AspectRatio -> 1.5,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"(b)"}, {0.3, 0.95}]];

Grid[{{a, b}}]
```

**UPDATE** (based on comment)

For a grid of these plots without spaces:

Change `PlotRange` to

```
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 1.1}}
```

Then:

```
Grid[{{a, b}}, Spacings -> {-1, 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the suggestion (I added the line). However, Grid is not an alternative to me, because I want to use LevelScheme for much more complicated manipulations with graphics. For example, I want to draw both panels side by side without any space between them. Grid doesn't have such an option afaik.